# Meteor.methods with ZeroMQ REQ/REP never returns answer

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, zeromq

Here is my method on the server:

```
Meteor.methods({
    dotest: function (ruleid) {
        console.log('Do test called with argument : %s', ruleid)
        var socket = zmq.socket('req')
        socket.connect('tcp://localhost:5555')
        socket.send(ruleid)
        socket.on('message', function(data) {
            console.log('Reply: ' + data);
            return data
        })
    }
})
```

Of course, it does not work, because the "return" fires after the dotest method ended.
How can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `Futures`!

```
Meteor.methods({
    dotest: function (ruleid) {
        var Future = Npm.require("fibers/future");
        var fut = new Future();

        console.log('Do test called with argument : %s', ruleid);
        var socket = zmq.socket('req');
        socket.connect('tcp://localhost:5555');
        socket.send(ruleid);
        socket.on('message', function(data) {
            console.log('Reply: ' + data);
            fut['return'](data);
        });
        return fut.wait();
    }
});
```

I didn't test this, but it should work. Happy coding.

Comment: As of Meteor 0.7.0.1, `Npm.require` is only available in packages.  To solve this, the `meteor-npm` package supplies `Meteor.require` which does the same thing:  https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/npm

Comment: Also, the `meteor-npm` package provides useful helpers around `future` which may be of interest: http://meteorhacks.com/improved-async-utilities-in-meteor-npm.html